# CSS3 Media Query cannot accept bigger min-width value

Tags: css, sass, media-queries

Based on the code i saw on w3schools: https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_mediaqueries_ex1

it is normally working like that as standard, where the larger the width is, style will use the corresponding query(in this case: min-width).

but,

what could possibly happen when you encounter this:
[css media query anomaly (or bug, or my bad(?))](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjoov.png)

1. why the browser respond to text-2xl rather it should at text-4xl?
2. is it misconfigured? how to find that?
3. im using sass
4. i have put meta viewport with default common value `width=device-width, initial-scale=1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such rule that higher value in media query takes precedence. In fact, both rules have same specificity and `text-2xl` is almost certainly defined later, overriding `text-4xl`.
You can read about selector specificity here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: hows that differ from w3school example? for my case, try change max-width to min-width, using value 375px & 640px

Comment: oh i found it. thats happen because i put the lower mediaquery below the higher value, which makes sense why it is not working. the last css declaration is the valid answer. thaankss